# Unable to access Alfresco's CIFS under Windows

Tags: linux, windows, networking, alfresco, cifs

I successfully installed Alfresco 4.2.d under Ubuntu 13.10 using IP: 192.168.0.200 (mbnoimi-virtual) and I can use the web interface without any problem through the network. But I can't access CIFS using Windows share.

I tried to access CIFS by using theses ways but all of them failed!

```
\\mbnoimi-virtuala

\\mbnoimi-virtuala\Alfresco

\\192.168.0.200\Alfresco
```

Error message

> Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem
>   with your network. To try identify and resolve network problems, click
>   Diagnose

Log of one of the attached PCs which can access Alfresco's web interface but can't access CIFS

```
C:\Users\user>ping mbnoimi-virtual



Pinging mbnoimi-virtual [192.168.0.200] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.168.0.200: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Reply from 192.168.0.200: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Reply from 192.168.0.200: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Reply from 192.168.0.200: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64



Ping statistics for 192.168.0.200:

    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:

    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms



C:\Users\user>ping mbnoimi-virtuala

Ping request could not find host mbnoimi-virtuala. Please check the name and try

 again.



C:\Users\user>nbtstat -a mbnoimi-virtual



Local Area Connection:

Node IpAddress: [192.168.0.8] Scope Id: []



           NetBIOS Remote Machine Name Table



       Name               Type         Status

    ---------------------------------------------

    MBNOIMI-VIRTUAL<00>  UNIQUE      Registered

    MBNOIMI-VIRTUAL<03>  UNIQUE      Registered

    MBNOIMI-VIRTUAL<20>  UNIQUE      Registered

    WORKGROUP      <1E>  GROUP       Registered

    WORKGROUP      <00>  GROUP       Registered



    MAC Address = 00-00-00-00-00-00





C:\Users\user>ping MBNOIMI-VIRTUALA

Ping request could not find host MBNOIMI-VIRTUALA. Please check the name and try

 again.



C:\Users\user>
```

CIFS configures: /opt/alfresco-4.2.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/subsystems/fileServers/default/file-servers.properties

```
filesystem.name=Alfresco

filesystem.acl.global.defaultAccessLevel=

filesystem.avm.name=AVM

filesystem.avm.enabled=true

filesystem.avm.stores=site,staging,author

filesystem.storeName=${spaces.store}

filesystem.rootPath=${protocols.rootPath}

filesystem.renameShufflePattern=(.*[a-f0-9]{8}+$)|(.*\\.tmp$)|(.*\\.wbk$)|(.*\\.bak$)|(.*\\~$)

filesystem.renameCSVShufflePattern=.*[a-f0-9]{8}+$

filesystem.setReadOnlyFlagOnFolders=false 

cifs.enabled=true

cifs.serverName=${localname}A

cifs.domain=

cifs.broadcast=255.255.255.255

cifs.bindto=

cifs.ipv6.enabled=false

cifs.hostannounce=true

cifs.disableNIO=false

cifs.disableNativeCode=false

cifs.sessionTimeout=900

cifs.maximumVirtualCircuitsPerSession=16

cifs.tcpipSMB.port=445

cifs.netBIOSSMB.sessionPort=139

cifs.netBIOSSMB.namePort=137

cifs.netBIOSSMB.datagramPort=138

cifs.WINS.autoDetectEnabled=true

cifs.WINS.primary=192.168.0.200

cifs.WINS.secondary=192.168.0.200

cifs.sessionDebug=

cifs.pseudoFiles.enabled=true

cifs.pseudoFiles.explorerURL.enabled=true

cifs.pseudoFiles.explorerURL.fileName=__Alfresco.url

cifs.pseudoFiles.shareURL.enabled=false

cifs.pseudoFiles.shareURL.fileName=__Share.url

ftp.enabled=true

ftp.port=21

ftp.bindto=

ftp.dataPortFrom=0

ftp.dataPortTo=0

ftp.keyStore=

ftp.keyStoreType=JKS

ftp.keyStorePassphrase=

ftp.trustStore=

ftp.trustStoreType=JKS

ftp.trustStorePassphrase=

ftp.requireSecureSession=true

ftp.sslEngineDebug=false

ftp.sessionDebug=

nfs.enabled=false

nfs.nodeMonitor.enabled=${nfs.enabled}

nfs.mountServerPort=0

nfs.nfsServerPort=2049

nfs.rpcRegisterPort=0

nfs.portMapperPort=111

nfs.portMapperEnabled=false

nfs.sessionDebug=

nfs.mountServerDebug=false

filesystem.cluster.debugFlags=

filesystem.lockKeeperEnabled=true

filesystem.lockKeeperTimeout=7200

filesystem.lockKeeperRefreshCronExpression=0 * */1 * * ?
```

P.S.

- Windows firewall is off
- I'm trying to access Alfresco's CIFS through Windows 7 32bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution; This issue happens because of samba conflicting so all what I did to fix it is un-installing whole samba from my Ubuntu then restart Alfresco.

```
sudo apt-get purge libsmbclient samba samba-common winbind
```

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco uses privileged ports for CIFS/SMB. If your  Alfresco is not executed as root then you should read this http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/tasks/fileserv-CIFS-useracc.html

You could also set the following loggers to get more detailed logs:

```
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.smb.protocol=debug
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.fileserver=debug
```

Comment: I already installed Alfresco from ROOT so there isn't any problem with privileged ports

Comment: to be sure if everything work fine from Alfresco server side (Ubuntu) I called 'iptables' 

` mbnoimi-VirtualBox ~ # iptables -L

 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)

 target     prot opt source               destination         

  

 Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)

 target     prot opt source               destination         

  

 Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

 target     prot opt source               destination         

 mbnoimi-VirtualBox ~ # `

Comment: A snippet of alfresco log after adding debug level to the logger: http://pastebin.com/h1b3fysj

Comment: you can read in line 40 in your log that your server is not OK
'Error initializing TCP-IP SMB session handler, Address already in use'
SMB Server shutting down ...

Comment: but I wonder, how this address already in use while HTTP server works fine?! I can access 192.168.0.200:8080 without any problem!

Comment: I guess your cifs port is already blocked (used by another process) or you're not allowed to bind to this port. Which users executes your tomcat?

Comment: but my Ubuntu doesn't block anything as shown in http://pastebin.com/hggbRt4b ... BTW When I tried to change Ubuntu IP from 192.168.0.200 to 192.168.0.100 Alfresco didn't accept admin password even when I started whole Ubuntu!

Comment: your IP maybe used to grant access to your DB...depends on your installation

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you mean?! I tried to install once again on clean machine but I still get same behavior